# Django Testing: URL mapping to the Class Based View

Tags: django, django-testing

I'm new to Django testing so trying basic testing codes. But it is showing one error in second test class

**Tests.py**

```
from django.test import TestCase,Client
from .views import PostList
from django.urls import resolve


class SmokeTest2(TestCase):
    def test_math(self):
        self.assertEqual(1+1,2)

class HomePageTest(TestCase):
    def test_root_url_resolves_to_home_page_view(self):
        found = resolve('/')
        print({'found':found})
        self.assertEqual(found.func(), PostList)
```

**views.py**

```
class PostList(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'home.html'
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.PostList.as_view(),name ='list'),
]
```

When i am printing `found` its showing the o/p

```
{'found': ResolverMatch(func=blog.views.PostList, args=(), kwargs={}, url_name=list, app_names=[], namespaces=[])}
```

But still I am getting this error

```
(blog_env) PS D:\django\blog_env\mysite> python manage.py test
D:\django\blog_env\mysite
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
{'found': ResolverMatch(func=blog.views.PostList, args=(), kwargs={}, url_name=list, app_names=[], namespaces=[])}
E.
======================================================================
ERROR: test_root_url_resolves_to_home_page_view (blog.tests.HomePageTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\django\blog_env\mysite\blog\tests.py", line 19, in test_root_url_resolves_to_home_page_view
    self.assertEqual(found.func(), PostList)
TypeError: view() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.069s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Comment: try, `self.assertEqual(found.func(), PostList.as_view())`

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge Its the same error showing after adding the above code..

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\django\blog_env\mysite\blog\tests.py", line 26, in test_root_url_resolves_to_home_page_view
    self.assertEqual(found.func(), PostList.as_view())
TypeError: view() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'`

Answer (score 5):

I was stung by this issue just now, ended up finding the solution in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Response.resolver_match)

class-based views need to be compared by name, as the functions generated by as_view() won't be equal due to different object ids, so the assertion should look like the below:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.urls import resolve
from .views import HomePageView

class HomePageViewViewTest(TestCase):
    def test_resolve_to_home_page_view(self):
        resolver = resolve('/')
        self.assertEqual(resolver.func.__name__, HomePageView.as_view().__name__)
```

Comment: This is in the official documentation and should be considered the accepted solution

Answer (score 3):

```
from django.urls import resolve, reverse
class HomePageViewViewTest(TestCase):
def test_resolve_to_home_page_view(self):
    resolver = resolve('/')
    self.assertEqual(resolver.func.view_class, HomePageView)
```

You can try this, it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are testing a Class based View, from the Traceback it can be seen that it's missing the request object. You can use the RequestFactory provided by the django.test package. Better read the following [RequestFactory Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/advanced/#the-request-factory) to get a good view of it. It will solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
from django.urls import resolve, reverse


class HomePageTest(TestCase):
    def test_root_url_resolves_to_home_page_view(self):
        response = self.client.get(resolve('/'))
        response = self.client.get(reverse('your_app_name:list'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```